# Showing the error : “No Internet Connectivity ” for Phoronix-Test-Suite :(

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, benchmarking

I have successfully installed Phoronix-test-Suite in my linux server [ Of the various options available, I have done it by downloading and extracting the software and installed it using their install.sh script ]

After this I gave the command : phoronix-test-suite list-available-tests, which is almost the very next step that can be given to know the available tests. After some wait, I am getting the following error :

[image: Phoronix-Error Image]

I have tried many things to rectify the problem.I am sure that there is no problem with internet connection as I am actually accessing the server remotely via putty and winSh. I have also tried setting the No_HTTP environmental variable of the phoronix_test_suite via the user-config as :  phoronix-test-suite user-config-set NO_HTTP=1 but again getting the following error:

[image: No_HTTP error image]

Is this because of the proxy-settings??? When I run phoronix-test-suite network.config, I am prompted to add the proxy details if necessary. Do I need to configure it? I am pretty sure that we don't use any proxy...
Can Anybody please help me in this please...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "Is this because of the proxy-settings" - Yes, in all likelihood, your proxy settings are to blame.  " am pretty sure that we don't use any proxy" - You don't seem 100% sure of this fact, you might want to make sure, you are not actually required to use a proxy (based on the error I suspect you do).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I will Provide the Answer since it took me some time to figure out the problem.

The "No Network connectivity" Issue is mostly due to one of the following three reason

1. Due to proxy settings not being configured to the phoronix-test-suite

   If your server uses any proxy-setting, we need to configure it to the phoronix-test-suite network configuration.
2. Due to IPV6 enabled or wrong DNS server
3. curl: (6) could not resolve host - error. This can be checked by pinging , for example. www.google.com.

Mine was due to the Wrong DNS Server. Hope this helps someone .

Regards,
..